# BigQuery data versus Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I cannot seem to the get the same number of sessions and users that I have Google Analytics Premium in BigQuery. I use the fullvisitorID to calculate the number of sessions (count) and users (unique count) should this not correspond to the numbers in Google Analytics?

Comment: Can you please post some query and numbers to guide better on you get fewer or lot more users than you expected. Also please know that `COUNT(DISTINCT)` is just an approximate number, read more at https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference

Answer (score 4):

While **@Felipe Hoffa** is correct that **COUNT(DISTINCT x, 10000)** will get you to a more precise number, it can can be further enhanced by making the 10,000 number into as much as 1,000,000 (Which I believe is the largest "Sampling" rate currently: [BigQuery Documentation of Count Distinct](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#countdistinct)).  As not a whole lot of people are using the Google Anaytics Premium data within BigQuery, the community for these question is very small. As someone who does use GA data within BigQuery on a Daily Basis, I can tell you that my research & validation has shown that the following metric definitions are about as closely aligned as you can get to what a Google Analytics UnSampled Report will tell you.

**Sessions**

```
count(distinct concat(fullvisitorid, string(visitid)), 1000000) as sessions
```

**Users**

```
count(distinct fullvisitorid, 1000000) as users
```

**New Users**

```
count(distinct (case when totals.newvisits <> 0 then concat(fullvisitorid, string(visitid)) end), 1000000) as new_users
```

**Pageviews**

```
sum(case when hits.type = "PAGE" then 1 else 0 end) as pageviews
```

**Unique Pageviews**

```
count(distinct (case when hits.type = "PAGE" then concat(fullvisitorid, string(visitid), hits.page.pagepath) end), 1000000) as unique_pageviews
```

**Bounces**

```
count(distinct (case when totals.bounces <> 0 then concat(fullvisitorid, string(visitid)) end), 1000000) as bounces
```

Comment: Update: BQ now supports the EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT() function.

Answer (score 1):

Update: BQ now supports the EXACT_COUNT_DISTINCT() function.

---

As @Pentium10 says, COUNT(DISTINCT x) gives approximate results for big numbers on BigQuery.

2 alternatives for exact results:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT x, 10000)
```

Gives an exact count distinct, if said count is less than 10000. Change value to go higher (slower results)

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT x
  FROM [table]
  GROUP EACH BY x
)
```

Also counts distinct values in an exact way.

Comment: I use a Simba connector to extract data to Alteryx from where I blend the data. How can it be that 'count distinct' is just an approximate number, if I export all the fullvisitorIDs, then I should be able to measure the amount of sessions and user in a day correct or am I looking at it wrong? Should I use another measure ?